# How to check yarn logs application id

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to running a bash script to run spark-submit and run a pyspark script but it was not successful. I want to check yarn logs using "yarn logs -applicationId ". My question is how can I find the appropriate application id?

Below is some parts of the error I got
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`1. Using Yarn Logs:`**

In logs you can see **`tracking URL: http://<nn>:8088/proxy/application_*****/`**

If you copy and open the link you can see all the logs for the application in Resourcemanager.

**`2.Using Spark application:`**

From **sparkContext** we can get the applicationID.

```
print(spark.sparkContext.aplicationId)
```

**`3. Using yarn application command:`**

Use `yarn application --list` command to get all the running yarn applications on the cluster then use

```
yarn application --help
-appStates <States>             Works with -list to filter applications
                                 based on input comma-separated list of
                                 application states. The valid application
                                 state can be one of the following:
                                 ALL,NEW,NEW_SAVING,SUBMITTED,ACCEPTED,RUN
                                 NING,FINISHED,FAILED,KILLED
 -appTypes <Types>               Works with -list to filter applications
                                 based on input comma-separated list of
                                 application types.
 -help                           Displays help for all commands.
 -kill <Application ID>          Kills the application.
 -list                           List applications. Supports optional use
                                 of -appTypes to filter applications based
                                 on application type, and -appStates to
                                 filter applications based on application
                                 state.
 -movetoqueue <Application ID>   Moves the application to a different
                                 queue.
 -queue <Queue Name>             Works with the movetoqueue command to
                                 specify which queue to move an
                                 application to.
 -status <Application ID>        Prints the status of the application.
```

**`List all the finished applications:`**

```
yarn application -appStates FINISHED -list
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. What should be the input of the ******?

Comment: Sample applicationId's are something like **`application_1516806604516_0002`**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `curl` to get required details of your application using `YARN Rest API`.

```
state="RUNNING" // RUNNING, FAILED, COMPLETED.

user="" // userid from where you started job.

applicationTypes="spark" // Type of application

applicationName="<application_name>" // Your application name

url="http://<host_name>:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps?state=${state}&user=${user}&applicationTypes=${applicationTypes}" // Build Rest API

applicationId=$(curl "${url}" | python -m json.tool | jq -r '.apps."app" | .[] | select(.name | contains('\"${applicationName}\"')) | .id')
```

**Output**

```
> echo $applicationId
application_1593019621736_42096
```